# How to modify the automatic GetLegendGraphic in QGIS when using QgsRasterLayer in the python interface to load data from a ncWMS server

Tags: pyqgis, wms, sld, getlegendgraphic, wms-time

tl;dr: How to add an extra parameter (using python) to the `GetLegendGraphic` request made by QGIS when a WMS layer is added using `QgsRasterLayer`?

UK Reading University developed a map server called [ncWMS](https://github.com/Reading-eScience-Centre/ncwms). It is basically a regular WMS server with some extend capabilities to serve meteorological and oceanographic data stored as NetCDF files (a format widely used in the metocean community). The extended capabilities are due to having to deal with the special characteristics of metocean data: time and depth/height dimensions, variable color scale, etc.

It's possible to see the server in action [here](http://godiva.rdg.ac.uk/ncWMS2/Godiva3.html). I managed to load a layer from this [server](http://godiva.rdg.ac.uk/ncWMS2/) in QGIS using the python console:

```
title = 'Test'
server = 'http://godiva.rdg.ac.uk/ncWMS2/wms'
layer = 'foam/U:V-group'
style = 'default-vector/default'
time = '2011-01-12T00:00:00.000Z'

finalurl = ('crs=EPSG:4326'
            '&srs=EPSG:4326'
            '&format=image/png'
            '&service=WMS'
            f'&layers={layer}'
            f'&styles={style}'
            f'&url={server}')

resultLayer = QgsRasterLayer(finalurl, f'{title} @ {time}', 'wms')

# HACK taken from Anita Graser's Time Manager:                           
# https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/blob/master/raster/wmstlayer.py
resultLayer.dataProvider().setDataSourceUri('IgnoreGetMapUrl=1&'
    + resultLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
    + (f'?time={time}'
       '%26colorScaleRange=0.0%2C1.0'
       '%26numColorBands=250'
       '%26logScale=false'
       '%26bbox=-180,-90,180,90'))

print('url query: {}'.format(resultLayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()))

if resultLayer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(resultLayer)
else:
    raise ValueError('Not a valid layer.')
```

resulting in
[image]

The only problem is that the extra parameter `colorScaleRange` that defines the minimum and maximum values for the color scale (in the example above 0 to 1 m/s for ocean currents speed) is respected by the `REQUEST=GetMap` but not by the `REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic` issued by QGIS when the layer is added. You can see that the legend goes from 0 to 2 m/s.

Checking the Tomcat log for a ncWMS server that I have installed on my computer (using different data and behind a proxy, so not public like the UK Reading University used in the example above)

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2020:11:58:36 -0200] "GET /ncWMS2/wms?time=2020-01-10T00:00:00.000Z&colorScaleRange=16.0,32.0&numColorBands=250&logScale=false&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=-38.00499999999999545,-59.00499999999999545,9.004999999999999005,-24.99500000000000099&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=670&HEIGHT=925&LAYERS=nasa_mur_sst/sst&STYLES=default-scalar/default&FORMAT=image/png&DPI=96&MAP_RESOLUTION=96&FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:96&TRANSPARENT=TRUE HTTP/1.1" 200 160372
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2020:11:58:37 -0200] "GET /ncWMS2/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&PALETTE=default&LAYERS=nasa_mur_sst/sst&STYLES=default-scalar/default&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image/png&LAYER=nasa_mur_sst/sst&STYLE=default-scalar/default&TRANSPARENT=true HTTP/1.1" 200 2916
```

it is possible to see that in the `GetMap` request the parameter `colorScaleRange=min,max` is present, but in the `GetLegendGraphic` it is not.

I am sure ncWMS is capable of dealing with this parameter in the `GetLegendGraphic` as shown [here](http://godiva.rdg.ac.uk/ncWMS2/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&PALETTE=default&LAYERS=foam/U:V-group&STYLES=default-vector/default&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0&FORMAT=image/png&LAYER=foam/U:V-group&STYLE=default-scalar/default&TRANSPARENT=true&colorScaleRange=0,1).

[image: GetLegendGraphic with colorScaleRange]

So my question is just how (using Python) to insert this extra parameter in the legend request before QGIS makes the `GetLegendGraphic` request.

Comment: Added the sld tag here because strictly GetLegendGraphic is an SLD operation (it's not part of the WMS specification).

Comment: So the issue is that QGIS (your code) uses the GetLegendGraphic for the named layer/style as advertised in the GetCapabilities response. and what you need to do is write a new SLD request using the `edal:ExtendedRequest>
<edal:Request>GetLegendGraphic</edal:Request...` information

Comment: Hi @nmtoken, thank you for the fast reply. Could you please elaborate more on how to use the ExtendedRequest using python in QGIS? I am a total beginner, it's my first time programming something in QGIS so I am completely lost. I only managed to load the WMS layer using pieces of scripts I found in GitHub.

Comment: It's a comment really, not an answer.  I think you won't be able to use in-built GetFeatureInfo capability in QGIS, you'll need to construct your own request from scratch, and inject the response in the appropriate location.

Comment: Hi again @nmtoken, I will try to search on how to do that. Thanks.